Is there a way to create a dragbar that is based on the Position instead of the Width?
I want to build a page that presents two articles next to one another, and make the screenshot of the original one (which is on the LEFT) change position according to the position of the dragbar, and NOT change its width while doing so.
I basically just copied the code from CodePen's free example.
And then changed the Height and Width of the screenshot of the article I took, from "Width: px; Height: px" to "Width: 100%; Height: 100%", so it will always fit the scale of the dragbar's div.
The Dragbar I used
I started writing a function but stopped, because I'm very new to programming and I don't really know all the options I have in order to change the functions from CodePen so that they will apply to the Position, instead of the offset Width.
Thank you very much!=)
This is the function that I need to change in order to get the effect (probably):
left.style.width = (e.pageX - bar.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';

This is an example of how it should NOT be (squeezing):
enter image description here
When it SHOULD move with the dragbar (off the screen) instead.
Thank you!!
The codes:


  // DRAG BAR (IMAGE) //

  var left = document.getElementById('drag-left');
  var right = document.getElementById('drag-right');
  var dragbar = document.getElementById('dragbar');

  var i = document.querySelector('image');

  const drag = (e) => {

    document.selection ? document.selection.empty() : window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    left.style.width = (e.pageX - dragbar.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';

  }

  dragbar.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  
  });

  dragbar.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  });


// Unfinished function
 / function moveLeft () {
 //   if (dragbar.document.addEventListener(drag)) { 
     // document.getElementById('drag-left').style.left = "-20%"
  //  }
 // } /
/* DRAG BAR (IMAGE) */

   .drag-container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

  [class^="panel"] {
    padding: 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .panel-one {
    width: 48%;
  }

  .panel-two {
    flex: 1;
    width: 52%;
  }

  .dragbar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(25, 0, 75);
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- DRAG BAR (IMAGE) / CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" ; href="copy2.css">

  <title>Copy</title>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- DRAG BAR (IMAGE) -->
  <div class="drag-container">
    <div class="panel-one" ; id="drag-left">
      <img src="Avatar Swamp.jpg" ; width="119.1%" ; height="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="dragbar" ; id="dragbar">
      <div class="slider" ; style="top: 50vh; position: sticky;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-two" ; id="drag-right" ; style="font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;">
      <div class="container">

        <div>
          <header style="text-align: center;">

            <h1 style="padding-top: 2%;">Title</h1>
            
            <p style="padding-top: 2% ; padding-bottom: 1.6%;">By Spongebob</p>

            <hr>

            <p style="padding-top: 2%;">Blah blah blah, some text to fill the space.</p>
         
          </header>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- DRAG BAR (IMAGE) -->
  <script src="copy2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>



enter image description here
enter image description here

The code you found is really bad. Resizing should use %, not px. Also, it's hard to understand what is that you need. OK, change position instead of width, have you tried to play with that property? Are you using images? text?

You should provide the code syntax of what you’ve done so far

Hey, can I add a new post bellow my question? Thanks! @MichaelOdenore

Why don’t you just edit it? Instead of a new post

Make the edit, so I see if I can help :)

Try this:
const drag = (e) => {
  document.selection ? document.selection.empty() : window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  var newPosition = e.pageX -
dragbar.offsetWidth / 2;
left.style.left = newPosition +
'px';
right.style.left = newPosition +
'px'; // Adjust drag-right position
dragbar.style.left = newPosition +
'px': // Adjust dragbar position
}

Tweak the CSS a little bit:
.panel-one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 48%;
}

.dragbar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(25, 0, 75);
  left: 0; /* Add this line */
}

Let me know if that works :)

Yes! It's almost perfect!
But when I press the dragbar only the image moves with the cursor and the dragbar stays in place, I need to send you an image, but do I just edit my question up above or add a new one here?

Post here, let’s see

Just edited my answer, give it a try now.

SCREENSHOT 1:
.
SCREENSHOT 2:
.
(Hope the links are correct)

It looks great man! But I have no idea how to adjust the dragbar position, I've learned only the very basics of js...

Just edited my answer again, if you found the answer useful, please click on the good check mark beside the answer. Thanks :)

You could vote up the answer as well, I believe that earns you something :)

Oh I haven't even noticed that mark, sure man!

Ok that still looks great (not sure if it stayed the same), but I the dragbar to stay in the middle without the new function changing its position, and the "drag-right" div to move alongside it as well.
Maybe it's because you put the "position: absolute" inside panel-one, instead of panel-two?
Already got your approval!

Try making the little tweaks and see if it suits what you want

Hey! I didn't want to destroy the code so I think it'd better if I'd ask:
Can't I just equalize "var = newPosition" to "var = dragbar" and by that making their positions be linked?
Thanks!

Yes I believe you can!

Cool! But I'm not quite sure what I need to do!
document.getElementById()..
Can you add it to your answer? Thank you!

Just did, you can further adjust the value of the newPosition as you see fit :)

Hey! I think using the transform: translate(% , %) attribute in the function would be more useful, do you think so? Thanks!

Go for it, with coding it’s all about trial and error :)
